# JQuery not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run my application in mobile version.But jquery is not working.It should check for the string in url and alert the message.Here is my code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("Already_Registered") > -1) {
       swal("Already Registered");
    }else if(window.location.href.indexOf("Successfully_Registered") > -1){
       swal("Successfully Registered");
    }
});
```

If anyone knows,please help me to solve this.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely separate. This question is about JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: Check the console for any errors. What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("Already_Registered") > -1) {
        swal("Already Registered");
    }else if(window.location.href.indexOf("Successfully_Registered") > -1){
        swal("Successfully Registered");
    }
});
```